# username registration without special characters

Tags: php

I have a website using the code bellow where i wonder how i can make it so that users only can use usernames that has no specialcharacters like "myname.is.cool" and only register names like "mynameiscool". and error message should appear saying "username can have not special characters".

```
/* register user */
if ((int) $_REQUEST['submitme'])
{
    // validation
    $title               = "user";
    $firstname           = trim($_REQUEST['firstname']);
    $lastname            = trim($_REQUEST['lastname']);
    $emailAddress        = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['emailAddress']));
    $emailAddressConfirm = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['emailAddressConfirm']));
    $username            = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['username']));
    $username            = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $username);
    
    if (!strlen($title))
    {
         setError(t("please_enter_your_title", "Please enter your title"));
    }
    elseif (!strlen($firstname))
    {
        setError(t("please_enter_your_firstname", "Please enter your firstname"));
    }
    elseif (!strlen($lastname))
    {
        setError(t("please_enter_your_lastname", "Please enter your lastname"));
    }
    elseif (!strlen($emailAddress))
    {
        setError(t("please_enter_your_email_address", "Please enter your email address"));
    }
    elseif ($emailAddress != $emailAddressConfirm)
    {
        setError(t("your_email_address_confirmation_does_not_match", "Your email address confirmation does not match"));
    }
    elseif (!valid_email($emailAddress))
    {
        setError(t("your_email_address_is_invalid", "Your email address is invalid"));
    }
    elseif (!strlen($username))
    {
        setError(t("please_enter_your_preferred_username", "Please enter your preferred username"));
    }
    elseif ((strlen($username) < 6) || (strlen($username) > 20))
    {
        setError(t("username_must_be_between_6_and_20_characters", "Your username must be between 6 and 20 characters"));
    }
    else
    {
        $checkEmail = UserPeer::loadUserByEmailAddress($emailAddress);
        if ($checkEmail)
        {
            // username exists
            setError(t("email_address_already_exists", "Email address already exists"));
        }
        else
        {
            $checkUser = UserPeer::loadUserByUsername($username);
            if ($checkUser)
            {
                // username exists
                setError(t("username_already_exists", "Username already exists"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would this cause your application a problem if they use non-alpha characters? There's nothing "special" about a full-stop. Your question is fine but I wonder what the point of such a feature really is.

Answer (score -1):

To enforce the requirement that usernames should not contain special characters and display an error message if a special character is used, you can implement validation logic in your registration process. Here's a high-level approach to achieve this:

Add an input field in your registration form for the username.

Use JavaScript to perform client-side validation to provide immediate feedback to the user as they type. You can use regular expressions to check if the username contains any special characters. If it does, display an error message near the input field.

Here's an example of JavaScript code for client-side validation:

```
    <form id="registrationForm" action="process_registration.php" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        <span id="usernameError" style="color: red;"></span>
        <br>
        <!-- Other registration fields -->
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
    
    <script>
        const usernameInput = document.getElementById('username');
        const usernameError = document.getElementById('usernameError');
    
        usernameInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
            const username = usernameInput.value;
            // Define a regular expression pattern that allows only alphanumeric characters
            const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
            
            if (!pattern.test(username)) {
                usernameError.textContent = "Username cannot have special characters";
            } else {
                usernameError.textContent = "";
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Additionally, perform server-side validation in your PHP code to ensure that the username does not contain special characters before storing it in your database. You can use a similar regular expression to check the username on the server side.

Here's an example of server-side validation in PHP:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

// Define a regular expression pattern that allows only alphanumeric characters
$pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/';

if (!preg_match($pattern, $username)) {
    // Invalid username format
    echo "Username cannot have special characters";
} else {
    // Username is valid, proceed with registration
    // Insert the username into the database, etc.
}
```

By combining client-side and server-side validation, you can ensure that usernames with special characters are not allowed, and users receive immediate feedback when attempting to use special characters in their usernames.

Comment: Your answer seems to ignore the code that the OP already has for validation. A good answer would explain how to make modifications to his existing code to ensure validation. Also, it seems like your answer may have been generated using AI which is currently not allowed.